# Can not run Spring Boot project in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to learn eclipse for a Java project. I used initializer(https://start.spring.io/) to set up Spring Boot using a dependency of spring web. I try to build my project in eclipse and I get the following error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)


2021-07-05 12:20:50.248  INFO 23536 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting SpringApplication v2.5.2 using Java 11.0.2 on MSI with PID 23536 (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.2\spring-boot-2.5.2.jar started by user in C:\Users\user\Downloads\app)
2021-07-05 12:20:50.252  INFO 23536 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-05 12:20:50.445 ERROR 23536 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:425) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.main(SpringApplication.java:1359) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share contents of your class  with main method , one with `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're running the wrong class. Run the class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 0):

This exact exception and stack trace is thrown in [`SpringApplication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/cbe4cff16b2f4d69ed0d6472f2bcafbe65fd5bb2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L425) (as of version 2.5.2) when no sources (`Class<?>...`) were provided. This happens when called directly or with the `SpringApplicationBuilder` like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .registerShutdownHook(true)
            .run(args);
}
// or
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplication().run(args);
}
```

To fix this, pass your class to the builder (e.g. `DemoApplication.class`) like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class)
            .registerShutdownHook(true)
            .run(args);
}
// or
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class).run(args);
}
```

Another option would be to run your application with the static helper method like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```